# Generate random number in C with probability

Tags: c, random, range

As I know the rand() function in C is an uniform random distribution.

So, how can I generate a range random numbers with probability?

### Example

Generate 200 Random numbers, ranging from `-100` to `100` is less than 20% total of numbers is negative?

Comment: Draw the numbers from -100 to +403. If the number is positive, divide by 4

Comment: get x as random in interval [1-100], if x<=20 then get some negative random number, if x>20 get some positive random number?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala this cant generate random number -100 to -25

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès the total of negative number always equal to 20% because rand() is uniform distribution random.

Comment: No not ALWAYS, it will be 20% in the mean, it could be less or more. Random is random... Uniform means that probability for each value is the same, that's all. I mean you have 20% chance to get a negative value, but that doesn't mean that you will have one! Having 1/1.000.000 chance at a lottery and bet 1.000.000 times doesn't mean that you'll win.

Comment: When you say less than 20% negative, is that strict? I mean that could be less than 20% but no more?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Yes, negative number must less than 20%

Comment: @MagicNumberA3B2CD in that case it is not about distribution any more. Just draw from `[-100, 100]` until you've got 40 negatives, after that draw from `[0, 100]`. If the number of negatives does not matter if it is less than 20 %, just do not draw any negative numbers at all.

Answer (score 0):

`RAND_MAX` can help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

static int rand_prob(void)
{
    int r = rand();

    if (r < RAND_MAX / 8) {
        return -(r % 101);
    } else {
        return +(r % 101);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", rand_prob());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can adapt the function to be reusable:

```
static int rand_prob(int percent, int min, int max)
{
    int r = rand();

    if (r < (RAND_MAX / percent / 10)) {
        return -(r % (max - min + 1) + min);
    } else {
        return +(r % (max - min + 1) + min);
    }
}
```

and in `main`:

```
printf("%d\n", rand_prob(80, 0, 100));
```

Comment: Can you explain the part RANDOM_MAX/8. Thank you

Comment: Yes, `RAND_MAX` is the maximum number that `rand()` can return, if the number you get is lesser than this max_number/8 then you are in the 20% of probability.

Answer (score -1):

If you want exactly 80-20 division among you numbers, then you can simply select **160** numbers from within the range `0 - 100` and **40** numbers from within the range `-100 - 0`.

(80% of 200 = 160).